# Submit form with html5 validation and jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, validation, required

I have a problem with validation of my form because if I use required attribute in each element of form and press submit the form is not processed until it is fill out the form, but in my file I add a function functions.js click on the button to send the data form, html5 validation is no longer respected and would like to know why that happens.

**Without jquery event**

[image]

**Form**

```
<form class="user-form" method="post">
<p><i>Todos los campos son requeridos!</i></p>
<p> 
    <input id="uName" class="span5" name="uName" type="text" placeholder="Nombre completo" required/>
</p>
<p> 
    <input id="uEmail" class="span5" name="uEmail" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required/>
</p>
<p> 
    <input id="uUser" class="span5" name="uUser" type="text" placeholder="Usuario" required/>
</p>
<p> 
    <input id="uPasswd" class="span5" name="uPasswd" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required/>
</p>
<p> 
    <select id="uType" class="span5" name="uType" required>
        <option value="0">Tipo de usuario</value>
        <option value="1">Emisor</value>
        <option value="2">Revisor</value>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <input class="saveUser btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Guardar"/>
</p>
</form>
```

**jQuery event**

```
$('.saveUser').on('click',function() {
data = $('.user-form').serializeArray();

data.push({
    name: 'tag',
    value: 'saveUser'
})

console.log(data);
return false;
    /* I put the above code for check data before send to ajax*/
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {

            } else {

            }
        }
});
return false;
})
```

Then, if I use jquery event to send data with ajax html5 validation with "required" attribute does't work.

If I change on click .save-user to on submit form, works html5 validation but not the code inside jquery event.

**Additional info**

The above form is used and included in two sections

```
<a href="#" id="lSignup">Sign-up Free</a>
<section id="sign-up">
    /* Form */
</section>
<a href="#" id="lEdit">Edit information</a>
<section id="edit-user">
    /* Form */
</section>
```

Then when I click in **lSignup** add an id to **user-form**:

```
$('#lSignUp').on('click', function() { $('.user-form').attr('id','save-user'); })
```

And if I click in **lEdit**..

```
$('#lEdit').on('click', function() { $('.user-form').attr('id','edit-user'); })
```

And after add ID to **user-form**, that form is showed to fill or edit field and save data with the event jquery to put up.

Comment: you can do that using `onSubmit` event. in that function use you `$.ajax` code and return `false` (this will prevent form submit).

Comment: The browser checks the required stuff when you do the form submit. Your code bypasses that. It means you would have to do your own jQuery checking based on the attributes.

Comment: If I use $('.user-form').on('submit', function() {...... works fine, but I need use $('#save-user').on('submit', function(){ .. when the user needs register or $('#edit-user').on('submit', function(){ .. when the user needs edit your info but if I use IDs instead class of form, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('submit','#save-user',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  data = $(this).serializeArray();

  data.push({
    name: 'tag',
    value: 'saveUser'
  })

  console.log(data);

    /* I put the above code for check data before send to ajax*/
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {

            } else {

            }
        }
   });
return false;
})
```

Comment: If I use $('.user-form').on('submit', function() {...... works fine, but I need use $('#save-user').on('submit', function(){ .. when the user needs register or $('#edit-user').on('submit', function(){ .. when the user needs edit your info but if use IDs instead class of form, doesn't work

Comment: use `$(document).on('submit','selector',function(){...})` bcz binding event dynamically.

Comment: I think an explanation about the suggested code would be needed to have a quality answer.